# add styling of text to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the code below to add a line break at a defined point. Is there a way to also add code to style the text after the line break?

```
 $('h3').html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace('Photo Course', '<br />Photo Course');
 });
```

Comment: Wrap your text in a span with an id then you can just get hold of it with j query and add style that way.

Comment: I only want to style the text after the new line break. Cannot add span in the text elsewhere. Its a long product title webshop-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can differentiate `:first-line`

```js
 $('h3').html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace('Photo Course', '<br />Photo Course');
 });
```

```css
h3:first-line {
  font-size: initial;
  color: initial;
  font-style: initial;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: gray;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>This is a title Photo Course of whatever I wanna here to be long enough</h3>
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!! This is what I mean. What if I have three lines and want to style them all different, can I use :first-line and :second-line

Comment: other than `:first-line` I don't think so... but there is `:first-letter` and `:nth-child` though http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: too bad, would've made it easy.

Answer (score 2):

You could add inline styles to the code after the line break like this:

```
$('h3').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace('Photo Course', '<br /><span style="color:red">Photo Course</span>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the text does not end after photo course.

Comment: I am using this code to have all product titles with photo course in it to line break there. the text after photo course will vary per product.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [css fn](http://api.jquery.com/css/) -  `$(element).css(property, value)`? 
 
like `$('h3').css('font-size', '20px')`. 
**Or** if you want to style without the break, you can wrap it inside a `span` and style that.

```
$('h3').html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace('Photo Course', '<br /><span id="to_style">Photo Course</span>');
 }); 
$("#to_style").css("color", "red");
```

**Or** you can add class to that span and have the style ready in the css.

```
 return h.replace('Photo Course', '<br /><span class="to_style">Photo Course</span>');
```

.

```
.to_style {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only want the text after the new line break to be styled. The line break is made in a long product title.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a span.  `'<br /><span>Photo Course</span>'`.

Then in the css stylesheet add something like `h3 span {color:green}`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the extra I don't  want to delete previous answer cause it can help someone else.
To style everything except break, you should give id or class to the break.

```
$('h3').html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace('Photo Course', '<br class="dont_style" /><span id="to_style">Photo Course</span>');
 });
```

And then style br separately

```
h3 {
   font-size: 20px;
}
.dont_style {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```